# Enabling SAS to read chinese character

Tags: sas, multilingual

Im having my **SAS installed in a Unix server**. I received a SAS data-set from one user which contains a column having chinese characters. Is their any way to read those Chinese characters without making any change in the config file

i.e. ***Is their anything i can do in code level which can be used only when i come across Datasets which uses other languages.***

Because its quite difficult to make changes in the config file as the application in the server is used by many users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically Chinese characters take up 2-bytes (unicode) per character rather than the 1-byte for most western languages.

SAS has something called "Double Byte Character Sets" for a permenent solution you can turn this on in the local SAS options.

Or you can do it programmatically when running a SAS script:

```
options dbcs       /*turn on DBCS*/

dbcstype=IBM       /*specify the IBM  mainframe
                     environment(encoding scheme)*/ 
dbcslang=CHINESE; /*specify the Chinese language 
                     (coded character set)*/
```

You can read more here:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/nlsref/63072/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1cknsutnoyi12n1s50375ayq5sv.htm

and here:

https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lrcon/z1315990.htm